# Wagtail: How to override default ImageEmbedHandler?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I've been having some trouble implementing Wagtail CMS on my own Django backend. I'm attempting to use the 'headless' version and render content on my own SPA. As a result, I need to create my own EmbedHandlers so that I can generate URL's to documents and images to a private S3 bucket. Unfortunately, though I've registered my own `PrivateS3ImageEmbedHandler`, Wagtail is still using the default `ImageEmbedHandler` to convert the html-like bodies to html. Is there a way for me to set it so that Wagtail uses my custom EmbedHandler over the built in default?

Here's my code:

```
from wagtail.core import blocks, hooks
from messaging.utils import create_presigned_url


class PrivateS3ImageEmbedHandler(EmbedHandler):

    identifier = "image"

    @staticmethod
    def get_model():
        return get_user_model()

    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls, attrs):
        model = cls.get_instance(attrs)
        print(model)
        return model.objects.get(id=attrs['id'])

    @classmethod
    def expand_db_attributes(cls, attrs):
        image = cls.get_instance(attrs)
        print(image)
        presigned_url = create_presigned_url('empirehealth-mso', image.file)
        print(presigned_url)
        return f'<img src="{presigned_url}" alt="it works!"/>'

@hooks.register('register_rich_text_features')
def register_private_images(features):
    features.register_embed_type(PrivateS3ImageEmbedHandler)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that your `@hooks.register('register_rich_text_features')` call happens after the one in the `wagtail.images` app; this can be done by either putting your app after `wagtail.images` in `INSTALLED_APPS`, or by passing an `order` argument greater than 0:

```
@hooks.register('register_rich_text_features', order=10)
```